# Since site-available is not here, where do I put all my settings?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian-squeeze

I noticed installing a fresh Apache (2.4.2) doesn't have the Debian structure. (`sites-available`, `sites-enabled`, (blank) `httpd.conf`, etc...), so if I wanted to move my virtual settings over from a Debian structured Apache, would I just append all my virtual hosts settings at the bottom of httpd.conf? What about SSL, do I have to `a2enmod ssl`?

It's so weird, I think the Debian structure is so much more organized and clean.

Comment: Where did you get this copy of 2.4.2?

Comment: Apache. Not Debian.

Comment: Yes. Allow me to rephrase my question. "Where did you get this copy of Apache 2.4.2?" Only Apache 2.2 is included with Squeeze, so you didn't get it from Debian's repository.

Comment: I got it from Apache's website. Not Debians repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can duplicate the Debian structure in a non-Debian system, by using the same pattern of `Include` directives in your own `httpd.conf`.  You won't get the helpers like `a2enmod` by default, but you could bring those across as well if you wanted.